# How to find out who changed the permission settings in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am using Folder plugin and AD groups to control access to folder. This morning a team can't access their project anymore and later I found the AD group assignment in Assign Roles has been changed to wrong groups. Is there a way to find out which id did it? We only have a few admin ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins does not appear to keep an audit trail by default, as stated [in this post](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/best-practices-setting-jenkins-auditing-and-compliance) on cloudbees.com, the folks that develop Jenkins.

The relevant lines:

> Many Jenkins users look for a recommend a strategy for keeping an audit trail. This article is supposed to be a gap filler until more comprehensive compliance capabilities in JE/JOC are developed.
>
> There are two open source plugins that enable you to track “WHO did WHAT?” in Jenkins:
>
> ...

The first plugin listed is [Audit Trail Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Audit+Trail+Plugin) which looks to provide exactly what you are seeking.

The description from the plugins page:

> Keep a log of who performed particular Jenkins operations, such as configuring jobs.
>
> This plugin adds an Audit Trail section in the main Jenkins configuration page. Here you can configure log location and settings (file size and number of rotating log files), and a URI pattern for requests to be logged. The default options select most actions with significant effect such as creating/configuring/deleting jobs and views or delete/save-forever/start a build. The log is written to disk as configured and recent entries can also be viewed in the Manage / System Log section.

I spent a few minutes looking through Jenkins various xml and log files, but could not find a log that contained something useful (username and/or timestamp). In this case it seems user auditing isn't built into Jenkins as of yet. Unfortunately it appears that you might not be able to determine who made those changes after the fact.